# How to get posts that user's friend posted on the wall of user on his birthday through Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, get

I am trying to build a Chrome extension and I want to get all the posts that people posted on the user's wall specifically on his birthday.

I tried to call through Facebook Javascript SDK, but it is not returning the posts that are posted by my friends on the birthday.

```
FB.api(
  '/me/feed',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

Rather, it is returning all the birthday posts in one post like this:

```
{
      "message": "Belated happy birthday bhaiii.....",
      "created_time": "2015-10-19T00:02:02+0000",
      "id": "578828115566706_848912165224965"
    },
    {
      "story": "Ritwik Jain and 40 others wrote on your Timeline.",
      "created_time": "2015-10-18T03:59:39+0000",
      "id": "578828115566706_848604468589068"
    },
```

How do I get each post individually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it return ANY posts at all? did you authorize with user_posts?

Comment: @luschn actually one has to use "me/feed" not "me/posts" to get all the post on timeline .... i have updated the question please look

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, the `/me/feed` endpoint is what you need to use - with the `user_posts` permission, of course. Facebook puts birthday posts together as it seems, but there is no other way to get the posts. Meaning, there is no way to get the birthday posts separately.

Endpoints for the user wall: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

Comment: I don't think so , as you can look each post individually on your timeline which means that they are storing them separately on different edges, so there has to be a way ...

Comment: what you see on your timeline on facebook.com is not always what you get with the api ;)