# Not getting all user posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to collect user information from a Facebook user. I get the following. I was wondering for data like below, How would I actually get access to those 74 posts?

```
{
  "story": "Bob K. and 74 others wrote on your Timeline.",
  "created_time": "2015-07-22T12:22:58+0000",
  "id": "10203067968xxxx73_10206102965xxxx"
   },
```

To get this result, I am entering the following in the GRAPH API Explorer:

```
me/feed?since=1434340800&until=1439524800
```

I am using PHP to traverse the posts right now. The following is working for other cases, but doesn't work for this one.

```
 $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

foreach ($posts_response as $element) {


    $FB_ID =  $element["id"]; //id assigned by Facebook                                                            
    $FB_OBJECTID = $element["object_id"]; //object id assigned by Facebook                                         

    $FB_MESSAGE=  $element["message"]; //content of the post                                                       
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: are those posts birthday wishes? in that case, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635126/how-to-get-posts-that-users-friend-posted-on-the-wall-of-user-on-his-birthday-t/35637225#comment58956411_35637225

Comment: Yes - these are birthday posts. However, when other people test the functionality of my app, they find that some posts are missing. Why are there posts missing?